# How to send information to a service using Intent in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, service

I created a service that updates the `GPS` coordinates and sends them to `FireBase Realtime Database`. The service starts when the user accesses the home page. I want to be able to send a String from an `Activity` to the service Class.The problem is that i can't call the `getIntent()` method  inside of the `loginToFirebase()` function  .

Here is the code that  I tried :

The service class :

```
 public class TrackerService extends Service {
  private static final String TAG =    TrackerService.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    buildNotification();

    loginToFirebase();

}

private void buildNotification() {
    String stop = "stop";

    registerReceiver(stopReceiver, new IntentFilter(stop));

    PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(

            this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Create the persistent notification

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Suivi de la position ...")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(broadcastIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert);
    startForeground(1, builder.build());
}

protected BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "received stop broadcast");
        // Stop the service when the notification is tapped
        unregisterReceiver(stopReceiver);
        stopSelf();
    }
};

private void loginToFirebase() {

    String password = "myPassword";
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth success");
                requestLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
    request.setInterval(30000);
    request.setFastestInterval(30000);
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    final String path = "locations" + "/" + 123;
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                try {
                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);
                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "location update " + location);
                        ref.setValue(location);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

}

The method from which I'm calling the service (In the activity ):

```
  private void startTrackerService() {
    Intent goService= new Intent(AccueilEtudiant.this,TrackerService.class);
    goService.putExtra("email",getIntent().getStringExtra("email"));
    startService(goService);

}
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use persistence . in your service use data you get from `sharedPreferences` , and in your activity , keep updating the `sharedPreferences`

gps info got updated => persist to storage => use persisted gps info in Service

The Service has to read the data from the chosen storage before sending the data.